# Using intervals to count chord occurrences

Tags: chord-theory, intervals, roman-numerals

I'm doing a statistical analysis on chord bigram occurrences, using chord progressions.

We wanted to deal with the A-transpose issue, since we mostly care about the intervals between chords and we shouldn't be bothered by each song's key.

My dataset contained chords in terms of musical levels represented as Roman Numerals like these:

```
['bIII', 'i', 'bIII', 'i', 'bIII', 'i', 'II', 'II']
```

The rest information about each chord is stored in two other lists, like this:

```
 ['maj', 'min', 'maj', 'min', 'maj', 'min', 'maj', 'maj']
```

```
 ['', 'add9', '', 'add9', '', 'add9', '', '7']
```

I turned these chords into intervals:

```
 [0, -3, 3, -3, 3, -3, 2, 0]
```

(Basically:  [4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3] -> [0, -3, 3, -3, 3, -3, 2, 0])

The rules I had to follow to make this conversion:

```
1    I == VII#                
2    IIb == I#    
3    II            
4    IIIb == II#    
5    III == IVb     
6    IV == III#     
7    Vb == IV#      
8    V              
9    VIb == V#      
10   VI             
11   VIIb == VI#    
12   VII == Ib
```

```
C = 1   C# = 2
D = 3   D# = 4
E = 5   
F = 6   F# = 7
G = 8   G# = 9
A = 10  A# = 11
B = 12
```

```
Intervals:
perfect_unison = 0
minor_second = 1, 11
major_second = 2, -10
minor_third = 3, -9
major_third = 4, -8
perfect_fourth = 5, -7
diminished_fifth/augemented_fourth = 6, -6
perfect_fifth = 7, -5
minor_sixth = 8, -4
major_sixth = 9, -3
minor_seventh = 10, -2
major_seventh = 11, -1
perfect_octave = 0
```

And now I want to count occurrences of every Bigram.
In the first analysis we won't be using the maj/min or any other information.
In the second round, we'll take into consideration the maj/min information.

My questions are:

- Should I count bigrams like [0, -3] : 1, [-3, 3]: 1, [3, -3]: 1, ... and so on, or should I convert each bigram to start from 0 or something? Am I thinking of this in a wrong way? I'm super confused.
- Also, should I turn all negative numbers to their equivalent positive (by adding 12 to each one of them)?

I lack some music knowledge - this is part of a project in computer science.
Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**
After some great help from @Aaron:

- Yes I should only use positive numbers 0-11, using mod12 for conversion.
- I shall choose bigrams as pairs of all consecutive intervals, in this case:

```
   [0, -3, 3, -3, 3, -3, 2, 0]
=> [0,  9, 3,  9, 3,  9, 2, 0]
=> [0, 9] : 1
   [9, 3] : 2
   [3, 9] : 2
   [9, 2] : 1
   [2, 0] : 1
```

Comment: These edits are helpful. I think my answer is still consistent with the question, but please let me know if I've misunderstood, or if clarification/additional information is needed.

Comment: @Aaron I was just reviewing your answer to comment with my questions! Your answer is amazing thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. Restate the question

Using the root movement between chords, what are the statistical occurrences of intervals between adjacent chord roots?

#### 2. Encoding the data set

The dataset — series of Roman numeral chord changes — is key independent, which means all songs may be treated as being in the same key. Call this "the key of 0." Thus, all `i`/`I` chords have root 0. The conversion from Roman numeral to Arabic numeral is as follows.

*NOTE: Because only chord roots are considered, chord quality (e.g., major/minor) does not matter. Therefore i/I, ii/II, etc. need not be differentiated. All capitals are used below. Enharmonically equivalent chords are also not included.*

```
I    = 0
bII  = 1
II   = 2
bIII = 3
III  = 4
IV   = 5
#IV  = 6
V    = 7
bVI  = 8
VI   = 9
bVII = 10
VII  = 11
```

#### 3. Encoding intervals

We also can map intervals to numbers, where the interval is expressed by the number of half-steps involved. Since Roman numerals (i.e., the chord roots) ignore differences in octaves, we need only twelve intervals (0 – 11 half steps). Further, since direction of motion is not considered (e.g. `bIII - i` could be down a minor third or up a major sixth), we only need intervals from the unison through the tritone.

```
P0    = 0
m2/M7 = 1
M2/m7 = 2
m3/M6 = 3
m3/m6 = 4
P4/P5 = 5
A4/d5 = 6
```

#### 4. Calculating the interval between chords (i.e., chord roots)

Given these encodings, the interval distance between any two chords X and Y is

```
                 /
                 |  if | Y - X | <= 6, then | Y - X |
INTERVAL(X, Y) = |
                 |  if | Y - X | > 6, then 12 - | Y - X |
                 \
```

#### 5. Building the result set

Given a chord sequence

[ X<sub>0</sub>, X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>, ..., X<sub>*n*</sub> ],

the set of interval distances is the union of INTERVAL(X<sub>*i*</sub>, X<sub>*i*-1</sub>) for all integers *i* in [ 1, *n* ].

#### 6. Example

Consider this chord progression from the initial data set.

`bIII  i  bIII  i  bIII  i  II  II`

Conversion to the encoding system (see section 2 above) gives the following working set.

`3  0  3  0  3  0  2  2`

For reference in this example, label these as X<sub>0</sub> ... X<sub>7</sub>.

Now calculate the interval between each pair of chords.

```
INTERVAL(X1, X0)
= INTERVAL(0, 3)
= | 3 - 0 |
= 3

INTERVAL(X2, X1)
= INTERVAL(3, 0)
= | 0 - 3 |
= 3

.
.
.

INTERVAL(X7, X6)
= INTERVAL(2, 2)
= | 2 - 2 |
= 0
```

The the resulting data set is

`[ 3  3  3  3  3  2  0 ]`

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I hadn't thought about reducing the intervals to 0-6 instead of 0-11 which is of course so right! However, it was my supervisor who told me I should use the 0-11 system I described, so I'm kind of confused here. I will update asap.

Comment: Also, could you please add an example to parts 4 & 5 based on any chord progression you want in Latin Numerals (or the one in my question), so that I can be sure I have a good understanding of what you're saying? (:

Comment: @Amy Okay, should be good to go. Please let me know whether or not everything is clear. In particular, if the 0 - 11 system is required, just let me know.

Comment: thank you! So - I totally get how you produce the intervals. Using the 0-11 system on your chord progression (I've made a script) I get: [-3, 3, -3, 3, -3, 2, 0]. So provided that 0-11 is required, should I convert [-3, 3, -3, 3, -3, 2, 0] to [ 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 2, 0] (by adding 12) or leave it as it is? Also, when counting occurrences, is it right to count occurrences of the pairs (9,3) (3,9) (9,3) (3,9) (9,2) (2,0) ? Would this be right musically speaking?

Comment: By the way, I'm doing this in order to extract statistical information about chord occurrences based on music genres and build a chord substitution / recommendation system.

Comment: @Amy Are you available to chat? If yes, please ping me there. I have some questions before I can answer yours.

Comment: Sure I just don't know how !

Comment: @Amy Try this: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126817/discussion-between-amy-and-aaron

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126818/discussion-between-aaron-and-amy).

Answer (score 0):

The analysis you're doing throws away some information that is musically important, such as whether a chord is minor or major (or diminished or suspended or an extended type), and also ignores modulations and key changes, so it's difficult to give a musically correct answer. However, if this is a programming exercise, here are some basics to get you started:

Chords in a major key (ignoring chord quality):

```
 0    I
 1    #I     bII
 2    II
 3    #II    bIII
 4    III
 5    IV
 6    #IV    bV
 7    V
 8    #V     bVI
 9    VI
10    #VI    bVII
11    VII
```

Chords in a minor key (ignoring chord quality):

```
 0    I
 1    #I     bII
 2    II
 3    III
 4    #III   bIV
 5    IV
 6    #IV    bV
 7    V
 8    VI   
 9    #VI    bVII
10    VII
11    #VII   bI
```

As you can see, even if you ignore whether the chords are minor or major or diminished, it matters whether the key of the composition is major or minor. In a major key, there is e.g. one step between iii and IV, whereas in a minor key, there are two steps between III and iv. So you'll have to work out whether each composition is in a minor or major key to translate the Roman numeral notation to scale degrees. Generally speaking, if it uses 'I' it's in a major key and if it uses 'i' it's in a minor key.

Then there is the question of whether you want to equate an interval from 0 to 3 to an interval from 1 to 4, or treat it as a different thing. In a simplified setting like this, I would consider them to be the same. This means that the information about the key of a composition is only used to decipher the Roman numeral notation, but not to distinguish between different intervals of the same size. E.g. the interval V-I has particular meaning that is different from vi-ii, but if you ignore the chord quality anyway, there's not much point in distinguishing between these two intervals.

Finally, considering the interval +7 to be the same as the interval -5 is normal in most musical analysis contexts, so I would suggest you do so too. You could e.g. notate all intervals as +0 to +11.

Looking at your example:

```
['bIII', 'i', 'bIII', 'i', 'bIII', 'i', 'II', 'II']
```

there is a contradiction, because the 'i' suggests a minor key, but the 'bIII' suggests a major key, and the 'II' would usually be either 'ii' or 'ii°'. You'll have to check how the conversion into Roman numeral notation was done, and whether it was done correctly. E.g. maybe compositions in minor keys were notated in their relative major key, or vice versa; actually, the example looks very much like a mangled version of:

```
[III, i, III, i, III, i, ii°, ii°]
```

that incorrectly used the intervals in a major key to notate a composition in a minor key. This really needs to be cleared up before you proceed.

Anyway, if we assume that the example is actually in a major key and ignore the chord quality:

```
['bIII', 'I', 'bIII', 'I', 'bIII', 'I', 'II', 'II']
```

then the scale degrees are:

```
[3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2]
```

and the intervals are indeed:

```
[-3, +3, -3, +3, -3, +2, 0]
```

or:

```
[9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 2, 0]
```

Comment: I edited my question and added some more information for better understanding! Thank you for your answer